# Reading sms from my android phone

Tags: c#, android, windows, winforms, android-library

i am working on a project that require me to read and send sms from my mobile phone.i firstly worked with gsm modules i am able to do it successfully using AT commands and for communication used the serial port.
but in case of my android phone first it do not create any comm port .second how i should proceed with this.reading and sending sms from phone using c# based windows application.i want to create an c# winform application to do this task. please guide me how i should proceed.
i also wanna know  do i will be able to access my phone gsm through at commands?like i did with gsm modules?
i searched online i found you have to download app on mobile phone to create virtual ports.